# Select multiple rows and group them by ID

Tags: mysql

I've been working on a project for quite some time now. Now I've got to a point where I can't think of a MySQL query that would return me all rows grouped by their parent. This is the table structure that I have:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | parent_id | name |
+----+-----------+------+
```

There are 8 parent_id values (1-8), and 20 id values for each parent_id (a total of 160). The way I am retrieving all categories and grouping them by parent_id is this:

```
$categories = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT id, name
        FROM categories
        WHERE parent_id = {$i}
        ORDER BY name
    ");
    $categories[$i] = $query->result();
}

return $categories;
```

Is there a way to put together a MySQL query that would do this for me?

This does not work:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM categories
GROUP BY parent_id
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: what will be your expected output?

Comment: why wouldn't `GROUP BY parent_id` work? What is the exact the result set you want? All I see as your requirement is `return me all rows grouped by their parent` which is exactly what GROUP BY on parent_id does

Comment: The query that I posted above only returns one category for each parent_id, not all as it should.

My expected output would be an array of 8 values (parents). Each of those would be parent to 20 array (categories).

Comment: @user726049 You want the output to have only parent_ids? Or you want the category name listed along side that?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9sZqzbgw

There you can see what I get with the PHP code above. I'd like to achieve the same using MySQL only.

Comment: @user726049 the link is broken.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/36669

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to ORDER BY the result set based on parent_id. You dont require a group by if you have to list each id from every parent.

```
SELECT id, name
FROM categories
ORDER BY parent_id
```

Comment: @user726049 see the answer and tell me. I couldn't make out much from the link you posted. It will be better if you can explain to us in words.

Comment: English is not my native language, thus I am not able to clearly explain what I am trying to achieve. That would not work, since categories have to be grouped by parent id. I think I'll continue to use the code that I already have.

Comment: @user726049 on one side you say categories have to be grouped by parent_id. in that case you only have record sets with one record per parent_id. But on the other side you say you need every id-name combo for each parent_id. How is that possible?